# PHP getting HTML email layout and pass variable

Tags: php, html

I want to send emails and store all email layouts in a seperate subfolder.
Let's assume the file `emails/mailLayout.php` contains something like

```
<a><?php echo $item["name"]?></a>
```

Approach to get the content:

```
$item["name"] = "John Doe";
$emailContent = file_get_contents("emails/mailLayout.php);

//send mail...
```

`$emailContent` should contain `<a>John Doe</a>` but thats not the case

Any solutions or better approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use php's output buffer :

```
$item["name"] = "John Doe";
ob_start();
require "emails/mailLayout.php";
$emailContent = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
//send mail...
```

`file_get_contents` does not interpret PHP code

Comment: You could even replace `ob_get_contents();` and `ob_end_clean();` with the one function `ob_get_clean();` to keep it more readable, it'll get the contents of the output buffer and clean it

Answer (score 0):

For this just do one thing :

For this first get the content from the .php file and then do something like this :

```
 $name = "John Doe";
 $text = file_get_contents("emails/mailLayout.php");
 $text = str_replace('USERNAME', $name, $message);
```

and in your mailLayout.php just replace the php value with some Constants.
for ex : Hi this is `USERNAME` or any unique value.

Hope it helps!!!